Unable to Access Docker Container Services on WSL2 from Localhost but Accessible via Public IP
I have an Ubuntu distro running on WSL2 with Mirrored Networking enabled, so the virtual machine and the host share IP and adapter. Inside the distro, I have Docker installed with several services running, listening on different ports. I can correctly access the services running directly on the virtual machine (e.g., SSH on port 22) using localhost:22.
My problem is that I cannot access the Docker container services from the host using the local IP (127.0.0.1, localhost, 192.168.0.9). The strange thing is that I can access them through my public IP over the Internet.
Diagram:
Windows 11 Host (Public IP: 10.20.30.40. Private IP: 192.168.0.9)
|
|__WSL2 Ubuntu (Public IP: 10.20.30.40. Private IP: 192.168.0.9)
   |
   |__SSH Server (Accessible from 10.20.30.40:22 and localhost:22)
   |
   |__Docker
      |
      |__Service 1 (Only accessible from 10.20.30.40:80)
      |__Service 2 (Only accessible from 10.20.30.40:443)

I have already done several tests, reinstalling various different distros and consulting the documentation, but I couldn't find the solution. Thank you very much.
Here is my .wslconfig config:
[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine=ipv6.disable=1

[experimental]
networkingMode=mirrored
hostAddressLoopback=True
 


It's probably not a result of misconfiguration but a pitfall of mirrored networking. When you access a service resides inside WSL from the Windows itself, the source IP would be an IP of the host itself, and with mirrored networking, it'd be also an IP of the WSL. I suspect that (currently) it by some means requires an actual process to be running in the "default" netns for its "hack" (for differentiating the WSL and the Windows host) to work. Docker containers under a bridge network are effectively "some other hosts", and by default docker leverages DNAT for their "exposure".

You may consider / try working around it by having the containers use host networking, or stop the docker engine from messing with iptables (so that the docker-proxy processes will come into play instead). (Obviously these could pose caveats you don't want.)

@Jorge Luis, Are you sure that you are actually running networkingMode=mirrored? Because I believe that in .wslconfig this setting should be in [wsl2], not [experimental] section (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config). Steps to verify: https://superuser.com/questions/1848010/win11-wsl2-how-to-verify-networkingmode-mirrored-is-effective.

I am having trouble with Windows + WSL 2 (networkingMode=mirrored) + Docker setup myself, not being able to access docker-compose service as localhost:port from the Windows host.
